# OutofBoundException on certain Hive queries

Tags: hadoop, hive

In my production environment I have HDP 2.5.6 running. In QA, HDP 2.5.3 running. Both of these HDP versions are referring to same sub-component versions - e.g. Hive, Tez, Yarn etc.

In QA, we have no issues running queries. However, in PROD, I am encountering the below exception.

[image]

The query that I am running is the following:

[image]

I have followed the below link as well.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+JoinOptimization

It does not help. I've aligned both my QA and PRD environments.

Comment: Please don't screenshot text. Cut-and-paste and code formatting works just fine, and is much more accessible.

Comment: @glennsl agree.. somehow when I was doing Ctrl+K and pasting the exception trace or the query. The form was complaining with an error.